# How can I fix a loose door frame?

Tags: exterior

Every time I shut my door to go in or out of the house the door frame moves. Also where the door locks it wont completely shut all the way. Which is hard to go out places, without worrying someone will get in. So I guess my questions here are:
1.) How to fix the loose door frame where it is loose? Would I be able to use long nails and hammer it in more?
2.)How would I fix the locking part of the door?(I have bought a new door handle thing.)
I am on a tight budget so what would I be able to use around the house you is very cheep to get.

Comment: Could you take a picture and indicate where the frame is loose? For your second question: Do you mean that you can't engage the door latch and the deadbolt at the same time? If that's the case, the strike plates are most likely misaligned. Depending on the severity, you can remove and re-install one of the strike plates if they're severely misaligned. Or you could file down the inside opening of one of the strike plates if they're slightly misaligned.

Comment: When you say "loose", do you mean it moves when the door shuts, or you can actually wiggle the frame with your hands while the door is open? How much does it move (1/8", 1", ..)?

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I'd do is one-by-one, remove the screws in the hinges and replace them with 3" #8 screws.  This should definitely secure the frame to the stud, and the door to the frame.  It might also fix your lock alignment problem, but if not, usually all that is needed is to move the strike up/down or in/out a bit.  Take the strike off completely - does the door latch correctly now? If so, you just need to position the strike correctly.  If it does not, that means the original hole is not aligned correctly and you will need to either enlarge it, or if it is way off, drill another hole and re-install the strike.